# Corrupt Git configuration in magit

Tags: magit

I updated My macOS to Monterey. After that, magit command yields "Corrupt Git configuration". I uninstall `emacs` and `magit` and install them again, but it does not resolve. How do I fix that?

Comment: Does running `git` from the command line work? What about if you do `M-x shell` from Emacs and try to run git?

Comment: I can resolve this. ```M-x shell``` and ```git``` yields
``` 
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```
Then, I found the following. Installing xcode resolve this issue.
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a

Comment: This is why I install git myself on macOS :-)

Comment: You should go ahead and add that information as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I can resolve this. `M-x shell` and `git` yields

`xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun`.

Then, I found the following. Installing `xcode` can resolve this issue.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. The answer by @hrkshr was helpful in finding a different solution for me.

I normally use git installed by homebrew. Homebrew's version doesn't have this issue: only Apple's `git` has this problem. E.g., if I do `git --version` from my shell, it works fine. But if I do `/usr/bin/git --version`, I get the error described.

So, my issue was that it was using the wrong `git` installation. I just had to switch it to the correct version by setting `(setq magit-git-executable "/usr/local/bin/git")` in my `.emacs`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, when update Xcode.

The reason was that I need to agree again with license.

If you run /usr/bin/git --version or Xcode, It will guide how to agree with license.